# Rename [half-minute-hero-2] → [half-minute-hero-the-second-coming]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

[*Half-Minute Hero: The Second Coming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-Minute_Hero:_The_Second_Coming) is the sequel to *Half-Minute Hero*, but the official name doesn't have the number "2" in the title.

Since the tag was created back when we only had a 25 character limit, and now we have a 35 character limit, can we redirect [half-minute-hero-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-minute-hero-2) to [half-minute-hero-the-second-coming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-minute-hero-the-second-coming)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Done!

- [half-minute-hero-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-minute-hero-2) -> [half-minute-hero-the-second-coming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-minute-hero-the-second-coming)